# Call to undefined function click() wordpress

Tags: jquery, wordpress, plugins

so I just started jquery yesterday and got problems with making a plugin in wordpress

```js
<?php
    $(document).ready(function(){
        ("p").click(function(){
            (this).hide();
        });
    });
?>
```

```html
<p>this should disappear</p>
```

Comment: You need to wrap your js code within `script`  tag and change `("p").click` to `$("p").click`

Comment: downvoters gone crazy

Answer (score 0):

//You have couple of mistakes. here is the working script

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yczoym58/1/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("p").click(function(){
    $(this).hide();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
"<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('p').click(function() {
        $(this).hide();
    });
}); < /script>";
exit;
?>
```

try this

Answer (score 0):

That error is because you didn't write the $. Also remember to wrap your code with `<scritp>`

```
<?php
echo '<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("p").click(function(){
        $(this).hide();
    });
});
</script>';
?>
```